# Simulating user interaction with a React component in a Jest test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a button React component that I want to test using Jest.

I want to test user interactions with the component.

How can I test the action of the button when the user clicks on the button in a Jest test.

My test looks like this:

```
describe('My button component', () => {
    it('does something when it is clicked', () => {
        const comp = (<MyButton onClick={onClick}></MyButton>);
        // ... how can I simulate a user click and assert the change in the DOM?
    });
});

function onClick() {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock the function using `jest.fn()`

```
describe('My button component', () => {
  it('does something when it is clicked', () => {
    const mockOnClick = jest.fn()
    const comp = (<MyButton onClick={mockOnClick}></MyButton>)

    component.find(MyButton).simulate('click')
    expect(mockOnClick.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)

  })
})
```

You can follow further instructions [here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-react.html).

Comment: Are `find` and `simulate` React methods?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. `find` and `simulate` come from `enzyme`

Comment: Thanks. And the native `onclick` event cannot be used directly because you are dealing with a React component that wraps the native DOM?

Comment: Event handlers in ReactJS (such as `onClick`) are named in camelCase format. You interact with your React component which then maps to the actual DOM element.